# Notation of a sustained note

Tags: piano, notation

I want to write a sustained A note for 2 beats. On that A note I want a B and C note. Both for 1 beat. What is the correct way to write that?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you want the B and C notes to be played one after the other. If you want to write this on a single staff you must use 2 voices with stems up for one and stems down for the other. The A note will be a half note with the stem down and the B and C notes will be quarter notes with stems up:

[image]

Other options include writing the A as two quarter notes tied together or using two separate staffs, one for each voice.

Comment: Aaaah thank you. A bit new into writing but this make sense.